# Pairing-based cryptography VS ZK-proofs: what's more efficient for threshold systems?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, secret-sharing, pairings, threshold-cryptography

In some papers (e.g. [1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1258486/), [2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265811036_Publicly_Verifiable_Secret_Sharing_Schemes_Using_Bilinear_Pairings)) the authors approve that pairings are more efficient than classic zk-proofs (e.g. proof of discrete logarithm knowledge) for the described applications (threshold encryption, PVSS).

Let's see the differences between these approaches:

1. Proof:

   - Pairings: there are no additional steps.
   - ZK-proofs (non-interactive dlog knowledge): one (sometimes more) multiplication (we consider elliptic curve cryptography) in the group, hash-function,  a couple of additional arithmetic operations.
2. Verification:

   - Pairings: pairing, obviously.
   - ZK-proofs: two (sometimes more) multiplication, one addition, hash-function.

But pairing is more expensive than point multiplication. If we consider a threshold system, verification is more important (because you should make a proof once and verify all other participants). In this case pairing-based cryptography is less efficient than zk-proofs. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care only about verification, and your protocols are such that the pairing-based approach requires one pairing, while the alternative (so-called "zk-proof") approach requires, say, 2~4 multiplications, one addition, and one hash, then yes, you are right: the pairing-based solution is less efficient. For a rough comparison, see page 14 of [my paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/246.pdf): if you pick some of the most common best choices for a pairing-friendly elliptic curve and a pairing-free elliptic curve, then the cost of a pairing will be roughly 8 times the cost of a multiplication (or exponentiation, since we were using multiplicative notations in this paper) in the pairing-free curve. There are two reasons behind that: not only do pairings require more computation than multiplication, it is also the case that the best-known pairing-free curves allow for more efficient operations than the best-known pairing-friendly curves.